# jQuery for loop adding [i] to "id" #name

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, for-loop

I´m new to programming in general so my code probably looks like s.... I am trying to automate the game result (1 / X / 2) depending on the amount of home and away goals entered in the form. Therefore I need some help with my jQuery for loop here. The code is below:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {

    $(document).change(function () {
        if ($('#hg' + [i]).val() > $('#ag' + [i]).val()) {
            $('#r' + [i]).val('1');
        }
        else if ($('#hg' + [i]).val() < $('#ag' + [i]).val()) {
            $('#r' + [i]).val('2');
        }
        else {
            $('#r' + [i]).val('X');
        }
    })
}
```

Anda what I want to do is to compare the values in each game. Home goals vs away goals (#hg1 compared to #ag1, #hg2 comp. #ag2 etc etc). The problem is that I don´t know how to change my textbox name.
I want it to look like this:

```
 #hg1
 #ag1
 #r1

 #hg2
 #ag2
 #r2
```

etc etc. where the number increases as [i] do.

The table code below:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All"></div>
<form asp-controller="BetSlip" asp-action="AddBetSlip">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="teamTdMargin"><label asp-for="HomeGoals1"></label> - <label asp-for="AwayGoals1"></label></td>
            <td id="resultTextBox">
                <input asp-for="HomeGoals1" class="resultTextBox" id="hg1" />
            </td>
            <td id="resultSpacing">-</td>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="AwayGoals1" class="resultTextBox" id="ag1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="Result1" class="resultTextBox" id="r1" value="" tabindex="999" readonly />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="teamTdMargin"><label asp-for="HomeGoals2"></label> - <label asp-for="AwayGoals2"></label></td>
            <td id="resultTextBox">
                <input asp-for="HomeGoals2" class="resultTextBox" id="hg2" />
            </td>
            <td id="resultSpacing">-</td>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="AwayGoals2" class="resultTextBox" id="ag2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="Result2" class="resultTextBox" id="r2" value="" tabindex="999" readonly />
            </td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Tippa rad" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

It could probably be done in the html table code as well instead of repeating myself. Anyways, all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that the for loop is just "plain" JavaScript. Googling "jQuery for loop" or similar things is going to be troublesome, since most jQuery documentation will assume basic JavaScript knowledge.

Comment: There is no need for the `id` attributes. Just use relative selectors `$.each($('tr'), function () { var inputs = $(this).find('input'); var hg = inputs.eq(0).val(); var ag = inputs.eq(1).val(); ... etc ... });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke This seem like a nice solution, but unfortunately I can´t get it to work. Maybe you could help me fix it? None of the other solutions worked for me. Here´s how I wrote my code:   $.each($('tr'), function () {
        var inputs = $(this).find('input').val;
        var hg = inputs.eq(0).val();
        var ag = inputs.eq(1).val();
        var r = inputs.eq(2).val();

        if (hg > ag) {
            r = '1';
        }
        else if (hg < ag) {
            r = '2';
        }
        else {
            r = 'X';
        }
    });

Comment: @PatrikW. `r` is the value of the 3rd input (not the input itself). It needs to be `var r = inputs.eq(2);` and then you set the value - e.g. `r.val(1);` or `r.val('X');` in your if/else blocks. But there are numerous other problems with your code so I have added an answer.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you so, so very much for taking your time and sharing useful insights :) this was really helpful and I´ve learned many new things. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no need to be using `id` attributes and it will be easier to use relative selectors to get the elements. Your script is also inefficient and is updating every input with `name="Result2"` even though you only need to change the input in the corresponding row (for all other 49 rows, your just updating the value to what it already is). In addition, your script will fail if the user clears a textbox or enters a value which is not a number. And finally your generating a lot of invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes (in the `<td>` elements)

Instead, handle the change event of the textboxes and update the result of the corresponding row. I also suggest that the result just be displayed as text in the table cell, not as an input (you should not be submitting that value back to the server)

Change you html to add a class name for the 'Goals' textboxes

```
<tr>
    <td><span>HomeGoals1</span> - <span>AwayGoals1</span></td>
    <td><input asp-for="HomeGoals1" class="goal home" /></td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td><input asp-for="AwayGoals1" class="goal away" /></td>
    <td class="result"></td>
</tr>
```

and the script would be

```
$('.goal').change(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var result = row.find('.result');
    result.empty();
    var home = row.find('.home').val();
    if (home === '' || isNaN(home)) {
        return;
    }
    var away = row.find('.away').val();
    if (away === '' || isNaN(away)) {
        return;
    }
    home = Number(home);
    away = Number(away);
    if (home > away) {
        result.text('1');
    } else if (home < away) {
        result.text('2');
    } else {
        result.text('X');
    }
});
```

Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xo2cf0kh/) for a working example.

Side notes:

1. There is no point using a `<label>` element since your current usage
   will not set focus to the associated control (the `for` attributes
   of the `<label>` elements do not match the `id` attributes of the
   associated control.
2. There is a major issue with your design if you generating elements
   with `name="HomeGoals1"`, `name="HomeGoals2` etc and your view
   should be based on a collection of a model containing properties
   `int HomeGoals` and `int AwayGoals` and the html should be generated
   in a `for` loop of `EditorTemplate` so the the html is
   `name="[0].HomeGoals"`, `name="[1].HomeGoals"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get rid of the `[]` and just use `i`:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
  $(document).change(function () {
    if ($('#hg' + i).val() > $('#ag' + i).val()) {
      $('#r' + i).val('1');
    }
    else if ($('#hg' + i).val() < $('#ag' + i).val()) {
      $('#r' + i).val('2');
    }
    else {
      $('#r' + i).val('X');
    }
  })
}
```

And there's no `change` event for the `document`. I guess you are looking for the same element there:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
  $('#hg' + i).change(function () {
    if ($('#hg' + i).val() > $('#ag' + i).val()) {
      $('#r' + i).val('1');
    }
    else if ($('#hg' + i).val() < $('#ag' + i).val()) {
      $('#r' + i).val('2');
    }
    else {
      $('#r' + i).val('X');
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
  $(document).change(function () {
    var elem_hg = '#hg'+i;
    var elem_ag = '#ag'+i;
    var elem_r = '#r'+i;
    if ($(elem_hg).val() > $(elem_ag).val()) {
      $('#r' + i).val('1');
    }
    else if ($(elem_hg).val() < $(elem_ag).val()) {
      $(elem_r).val('2');
    }
    else {
      $(elem_r).val('X');
    }
  })
}
```